# Showing image if specific criteria is met in Laravel

Tags: php, html, laravel, laravel-5

I am completely new at Laravel and I am making a dashboard. On this dashboard I want to show an image of a tick if the `lastdatasync`(timestamp data type) records are within the last 24hrs. if it is more than 24hrs(say last week) then the image of an X will show. I have done the sql command for this but I am not sure where to place it in the project.

sql:

```
select count(*) as failed from stores where isactive=1 and date_add(currentdatasync, INTERVAL 1 DAY) < Now()
```

Comment: Please check out the documentation at: https://laravel.com/docs/master/database#running-queries to see an example of a select query

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about your actual implementation logic but you can do something like this:

Run the query and get your result in controller like:

```php
class DashboardController extends Controller
{
    public function view()
    {
        $failed = DB::table('stores')
            ->where('isactive', 1)
            ->whereRaw("(currentdatasync + INTERVAL '1 DAY') < Now()")
            ->count('*');

        return view('some.view')->withFailed($failed);
    }
}
```

And inside your view (here `some/view.blade.php`):

```php
@if ($failed)
    <img src="{{ asset('imgs/tick.png') }}">
@else
    <img src="{{ asset('imgs/cross.png') }}">
@endif
```

by the way, asset will try to look for the `imgs/tick.png` from inside the `public` directory.

Comment: Okay I may have another issue, @Mohsen Nazari. So my dashboard view does not have controller linked to it. I used middleware to authenticate admins to only enter and when they do it takes them to the dashboard view. So the Dashboard is just a view. There is  dashboardController though. Is there anything I can do?